# Passing params between XSLT files

Tags: xml, xslt, apache-fop

I'm trying to create some kind of XSLT config file which looks like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" exclude-result-prefixes="fo">
    <xsl:variable name="font_size" value="5pt"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thing I want to achive is to call the variable "font_size" in other XSLT file to define.

I was trying to do this like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" exclude-result-prefixes="fo">
    <xsl:include href="config.xsl"/>
      <fo:block font-size="$font-size">
          ...
```

But unfortunately it didn't work out.

Comment: Did you try `<fo:block font-size="{$font-size}">`? Otherwise no variable will not be recognized in a literal attribute value, whether it is defined in your main module or in an included module is not really relevant here.

Comment: It works! But I also have change the config file to: `<xsl:variable name="font-size">5pt</xsl:variable>` Thanks you :)

Comment: @KubaKolybacz: That should also work.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, xsl:variable does not have a "value" attribute. I think you meant "select".

Secondly, if the variable is named "font_size" then it cannot be referenced as "$font-size" (note the punctuation)

Thirdly, you need to put the variable reference in curly braces: `font-size="{$font_size}"/>.

Fourthly, if you're trying to generate an fo:block element, then it needs to appear inside a template or function. An fo:block element as an immediate child of xsl:stylesheet is permitted, but achieves nothing.